# How to use ADB wireless on WSL?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, adb

Is this possible?  I spent a good hour trying figure out why it wasn't working before I remembered WSL can't even establish a connection with *any* physical USB interface (out-of-box, anyway).  What would need to be done to get it to work?

Comment: WLS you mean WSL? If you’re looking for ADB why don’t you use the Android Subsystem instead on Windows 11?

Comment: Use the edit button and clarify your question please.

Comment: I see no reason that this won't work (either USB or wireless).  Please add details on your research (see [Search, and Research ...](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask), and perhaps we can see what's going on.  Please do focus on *one question* (either USB or wireless) per post, though.  Thanks!